# unable to run scripts on simulator from cron tab

Tags: ios, cron, sikuli

We are using sikuli tool for mobile automation on our MAC OSX 10.7.3
I have written a shell script to open simulator and to run scripts on simulator

```
/Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/FoneMonkey/bin/iphonesim launch              /Users/ezprintsqa/Documents/Xcode/DerivedData/SnapCards-   btmjdowsgmixpvdyfxfvhxtoihab/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SnapCardsFoneMonkey.app&

/Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/Sikuli-IDE.app/sikuli-ide.sh -r /Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/SikuliWorkSpace/SnapcardsTestSuite1.sikuli
```

When I execute from command line I can see simulator opening and scripts getting executed on simulator.
But when I do same thing using cron tab I can see only simulator opening but the tool can't identify the simulator now to run scripts, the tool throws error message that it is unable to identify the simulator.

When the tool is able to identify the simulator while running from command prompt why is it unable to identify while running from crontab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:
the tool throws error message that it is unable to identify the simulator.

Do I understand right, that the script throws a FindFailed exception, meaning, that some image (might be the visual identification of the simulator window) is not found on the screen within the standard waiting time of 3 seconds?

I this is the case, you should give more time to the simulator to start up in the crontab case, either by adding a wait(n) at the beginning of the Sikuli script or use wait(image, n) to wait longer for the image to appear